# can't understand this LALR(1) parsing algorithm in aho & Ullman book

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lalr

The algorithm for computing the lookaheads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Yzb.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Yzb.jpg)

The algorithm says to compute $CLOSURE( { [A \rightarrow \alpha . \beta , # ]}) $
[image: the worked out example]

In the worked out example above, When they compute closure of ${[
S^\prime \rightarrow .S ,#]} $ how come the item $[ L \rightarrow . * R, =/# ] $ has the dummy symbol $#$ as its lookahead when $ FIRST(=R#) = { = } $ contains only the $=$ terminal symbol?

The closure algorithm provided in the book says the lookaheads of generated item will be FIRST($\alpha) where alpha is the string of grammar symbols following the non terminal from which the item is generated, but in the given example the string contains the terminal $=$ as the first symbol so the lookahead should just be $ = $ but the example shows the lookahead also containing $ # $ in addition to $ = $.

Comment: Try the [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) subsite instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `S -> . L = R, #` contributes only `=` to the lookahead set for `L -> . * R`.

But `R -> . L, #` also has a dot before the `L`, so also leads to the `L -> . * R` item, and *it* contributes `#` to that item's lookahead set.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was really lost with this one. Thank you for pointing out this important detail